# Derivative of Fourier transform with respect to intermediate variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

I am studying a system with a characteristic, say $\zeta$, that varies in 3D real space. I can use this characteristic to calculate the value of a second characteristic $\beta$. In other words, I have a system with
$$ \beta(\zeta(x)) $$
I know $\beta(\zeta)$ analytically and can take $d\beta/d\zeta$ easily. I do not know $\zeta(x)$ analytically.

I would like to take the derivative of the Fourier transform of $\beta$ w.r.t $\zeta$, as in
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\beta(\zeta(x))e^{-2\pi i k x} dx$$
My objective is to produce a new function of $\zeta$ and then take its Fourier transform, so I would like to convert this to the transform of the derivative
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} \Big(\beta(\zeta(x))e^{-2\pi i k x} \Big)dx$$
using differentiation under the integral. However, it's not clear to me that this is a legal move given that my derivative is w.r.t. an intermediate variable. Is this allowed? If not, what would be the recommended approach here?